# Is there a LinkedList collection that supports dictionary type operations

Tags: c#, dictionary, linked-list

I was recently profiling an application trying to work out why certain operations were extremely slow. One of the classes in my application is a collection based on LinkedList. Here's a basic outline, showing just a couple of methods and some fluff removed:

```
  public class LinkInfoCollection : PropertyNotificationObject, IEnumerable<LinkInfo>
  {

    private LinkedList<LinkInfo> _items;

    public LinkInfoCollection()
    {
      _items = new LinkedList<LinkInfo>();
    }

    public void Add(LinkInfo item)
    {
      _items.AddLast(item);
    }

    public LinkInfo this[Guid id]
    { get { return _items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id); } }

  }
```

The collection is used to store hyperlinks (represented by the LinkInfo class) in a single list. However, each hyperlink also has a list of hyperlinks which point to it, and a list of hyperlinks which it points to. Basically, it's a navigation map of a website. As this means you can having infinite recursion when links go back to each other, I implemented this as a linked list - as I understand it, it means for every hyperlink, no matter how many times it is referenced by another hyperlink, there is only ever one copy of the object.

The ID property in the above example is a GUID.

With that long winded description out the way, my problem is simple - according to the profiler, when constructing this map for a fairly small website, the indexer referred to above is called no less than 27906 times. Which is an extraordinary amount. I still need to work out if it's really necessary to be called that many times, but at the same time, I would like to know if there's a more efficient way of doing the indexer as this is the primary bottleneck identified by the profiler (also assuming it isn't lying!). I still needed the linked list behaviour as I certainly don't want more than one copy of these hyperlinks floating around killing my memory, but I also do need to be able to access them by a unique key.

Does anyone have any advice to offer on improving the performance of this indexer. I also have another indexer which uses a URI rather than a GUID, but this is less problematic as the building incoming/outgoing links is done by GUID.

Thanks;
Richard Moss

Comment: _Why_ do you need a linked-list behavior?

Comment: Well. Normally I don't have collections capable of infinite recursion. But if Link A points to Link B which also points back to Link A, it means you can happily bounce from a to b to a to b for ever and a day. So I had thought from the description of a LinkedList it would be better served for the job. Maybe I'm mistaking, and a dictionary will suffice ... but I won't know unless I ask someone with more knowledge :)

Comment: Collections doesn't care about references in its contents.  LinkedList is very much the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `Dictionary<Guid, LinkInfo>`.

Comment: Or [KeyedCollection<Guid, LinkInfo>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

Comment: Normally I do base collections of Dictionary, this is the first time I've used LinkedList as a base. As MSDN states "You can remove nodes and reinsert them, either in the same list or in another list, which results in no additional objects allocated on the heap."

Using a dictionary would negate this advantage surely? Or is it not worth worrying about?

Comment: @Richard: The only issue with a dictionary is that it will occasionally need to resize its internal array (creating a new one and discarding the old one).  **Don't worry about it**.  If you're concerned, you can set the capacity in advance to avoid unnecessary resizes.

Comment: I think the MSDN is saying that LinkedList is doing something with it's internal `Link` object. I don't think they meant to imply that the other collection classes make copies of the objects inserted into them.

Comment: @David: Correct.  A collection cannot _possibly_ copy its contents.  (Unless it's a collection of structs, in which case it _must_ copy its contents)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guess I've engineered this one completely wrong :) I'll just go with the Dictionary that I use almost everywhere else.

Comment: After modifying the collection to use a Dictionary instead, the time of a long operation has gone from 11 seconds to a quarter of a second. I haven't spotted any side effects yet but I'm pretty pleased with the performance ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use LinkedList in order to have only one copy of each LinkInfo in memory. Remember that LinkInfo is a managed reference type, and so you can place it in any collection, and it'll just be a reference to the object that gets placed in the list, not a copy of the object itself.

That said, I'd implement the LinkInfo class as containing two lists of Guids: one for the things this links to, one for the things linking to this. I'd have just one `Dictionary<Guid, LinkInfo>` to store all the links. Dictionary is a very fast lookup, I think that'll help with your performance.

The fact that this[] is getting called 27,000 times doesn't seem like a big deal to me, but what's making it show up in your profiler is probably the `SingleOrDefault` call on the `LinkedList`. Linked lists are best for situations where you need fast insertions & removals, particularly in the middle of the list. For quick lookups, which is probably more important here, let the Dictionary do its work with hash tables.